# ow to refer to the location of minima in a different matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab, I have a set of minima from a n*m matrix (the min of columns)

```
[new locnew] = min(matrixA)
```

So locnew is a vector with n indices of where the minimum of that column was located.

I want to edit the location of those minima is a different matrix of the same size. For this I have two very crude solutions:

```
for j = 1:n
    matrixB(locnew(j),j) = 0;
end
```

and

```
matrixB(locnew + m*(0:(n-1))) = 0
```

Both ways feel very crude and inefficient (n is going to be big). Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: This somehow makes all the edits to the first column.

Comment: Your second method is your best option. The only other way I would try it is using `sub2ind` but I doubt that will be faster than using `locnew + m*(0:(n-1))`

Comment: Also you loop should range to `m` instead of `n` shouldn't it? So it shouldn't really matter if `n` is big.

Comment: So, you want to set the minimum of each column to `0`? `result = bsxfun(@eq, matrixA, min(matrixA,[],1)).*matrixA` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably bite the bullet and do this in a loop, but if you really don't want to then try single position indexing. You'll need to convert your 'locnew' from a row index into a position, using the length of each column.
e.g:

```
m = [1,2,4,6,7;3,8,4,3,7;,2,7,3,6,0]

m =

 1     2     4     6     7
 3     8     4     3     7
 2     7     3     6     0

[new locnew] = min(m)

locnew =

 1     1     3     2     3
```

create 'z', which will be the number to add to your row index:

```
z = 0:size(m,1):numel(m) - size(m,1)

locnew2 = locnew + z;
```

you can then use that as your index, e.g. to set all your mins in 'm' to 0:

```
m(locnew2) = 0;

m =

   NaN   NaN     4     6     7
     3     8     4   NaN     7
     2     7   NaN     6   NaN
```